# How do I fix the error "AttributeError: 'pygame.Surface' object has no attribute 'units'"?

Tags: python, pygame, spyder, psychopy

I am very new to Python (programming in general). I am trying to display a gabor patch and a mask. I have copy-pasted the code from Dalmaijer's book (Python for Experimental Psychologists). But I keep getting the attribution error.

```
import pygaze
from pygaze.display import Display
from pygaze.screen import Screen
import pygaze.libtime as timer
import numpy
from psychopy.visual import GratingStim
disp = Display()
gabor = GratingStim(pygaze.expdisplay, tex='sin', mask='gauss', sf=0.05, size=200)
gaborscreen = Screen()
gaborscreen.screen.append(gabor)
noise = (numpy.random.rand(64, 64) * 2) - 1
noisepatch = GratingStim(pygaze.expdisplay, tex='noise', mask='gauss', size=200)
noisescreen = Screen()
noisescreen.screen.append(noisepatch)
disp.fill(gaborscreen)
disp.show()
timer.pause(1000)
disp.fill(noisescreen)
disp.show()
timer.pause(2000)
disp.close()
```

This is the error I keep getting:

```
 File "C:\Program Files (x86)\WPy64-3720\python-3.7.2.amd64\lib\site-packages\psychopy\visual\basevisual.py", line 1124, in units
   self.__dict__['units'] = self.win.units

AttributeError: 'pygame.Surface' object has no attribute 'units'
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score -1):

From this online source:

http://forum.cogsci.nl/index.php?p=/discussion/2245/images-appearing-as-black-boxes-after-many-trials

> > I have tried switching the backend from PsychoPy to xpyriment |
> >     legacy, but with the later two I immediately get an AttributeError
> >     'pygame.Surface object has no attribute 'units'.
>
> That's because you are using PsychoPy code directly, in which case you
>   must use the psycho backend. But there's nothing in your code that
>   couldn't be done just as easily using OpenSesame's native Python
>   libraries, which are backend-independent, or Expyriment, which
>   requires the xpyriment backend.
>
> http://osdoc.cogsci.nl/3.1/manual/python/canvas
>   http://docs.expyriment.org/ Is there any particular reason that you
>   need PsychoPy?

Comment: I don‘t think OP is using OpenSesame.